# How do I set up persistent volume redundancy in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

Let's say I have a Kubernetes cluster with 2 nodes. A control plane, and a worker.

If I use persistent volumes in my pods, will Kubernetes store my data in both nodes, for redundancy? And is redundancy even default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handling redundancy of storage is not something that's done by Kubernetes. Instead, it highly depends on the specific storage interface that you are using.

More precisely:

- Local storage (and HostPath): These are created on specific worker nodes, i.e. the one you have in your cluster. It's really not much more than a directory on that node.
- CSI: This allows to use a storage system that handles redundancies and the like, i.e. by some clustered storage system. The official [list of available CSI drivers](https://kubernetes-csi.github.io/docs/drivers.html) provides a good starting point to identify one that suits your needs.